# How to get logging info for HikariCP

Tags: hikaricp

Using Hibernate 4.3.1, Hikari 2.3.2.

I have configured this in the hibernate persistence xml

```
...
<property name="hibernate.hikari.leakDetectionThreshold" value="3000" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.poolName" value="KikariTest" />
<property name="hibernate.hikari.registerMbeans" value="true" />
```

And this in my log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
log4j.additivity.com.zaxxer.hikari=false
```

Im not seeing any logging information printed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a whole day to get this right! Turns out I was using log4j libs only, whereas a needed to include the slf4j libs.

Comment: Ah, sorry it took so long to chase down, but glad you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `log4j.additivity.com.zaxxer.hikari=true` (or not set at all, left at default).  additivity=false means don't inherit the parent's appender, which probably means there is no appender at all.

Comment: I have tried without that line and still no success.  and just to be sure, I got the logger via the com.zaxxer...  name and printed some debug to it just to make sure it was looking at the right place.  thanks for suggestion, I'm sure it must be something along those lines.  I'm setting all hikari properties in xml, nothing in code.  is that ok?

Answer (score -2):

Remove theese jars from your classpath or lib directory if you have.

logback-classic-1.1.7.jar
logback-core-1.1.7.jar

Comment: You posted a nearly-identical answer to another question.